# An issue with Gradle

Tags: android, google-maps

I used this tutorial: developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start
This is my gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.amine.myapplicationmapamine"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.8.00'
}
```

I can see a map in my emulator, but it's not clear and I get this error :

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you have any jars in your 'libs' folder?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add more info and delete the "answers" below

Comment: And those "messages" show no errors. My answer allows you to build and run the app. I do not know what the problem with the map is

Answer (score 1):

There's not really enough detail to completely answer this, but it's recommended to use the correct version of Google Play Services.

Not sure where you got this line from because that tutorial doesn't use this.

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.8.00'
```

[The latest](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup) is this. You seem to have an extra `0`

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.8.0'
```

Also, there are [working sample apps on Github](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-samples/tree/master/ApiDemos)  that come from that tutorial that you more or less could copy from.

And I find the [configuration page](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/config) is more "getting started" than the actual start page.

Answer (score 1):

replace `:compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.8.00'`
with `:compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.8.0'`